# Consistency of an estimator $\widehat{\theta}_n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n \psi(X_i-\theta)=0$

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, parameter-estimation

About problem 4.4a page 57 of

https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.j.k.kleijn/AsympStat-LecNotes2010.pdf

For this problem I could check the conditions of lemma 4.9 except the latter with epsilons.
First I wrote 
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \psi(X_i-\theta) \xrightarrow{P} -\mathbb{E} \psi(X_1-\theta)
\end{align} 
My thought was $\psi$ is odd, so $\theta_0$ has s.t. to do with that, because otherwise the oddness would be too coincidentally.
Anyway we must have $\theta_0$ such that 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x-\theta_0)f_{X_1}(x)dx = 
0
\end{align} 
I can imagine that there is such $\theta_0$, but expressing it in the density is my main problem.

Is there anyone with such an expression? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In this case $\psi(x)=\tanh(x/2)$ is strictly monotone increasing; so is $\theta\mapsto -\mathbb E \psi(X_1-\theta).$  This should make it easier to apply 4.9.

Comment: I know how to apply 4.9, but expressing $\theta_0$ in the density seems to be harder